# How to capture google account of viewer using google apps script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

So i have a google sheet table to store data of my team (name and gmail account). I will assign every user with different task in my project. I create a web app (user interface) using apps script so my user can interact with the task.  In this case, assumes all my users will be using google chrome browser and need to login to the google account on their own browser. For users who use other browser or if not sign in to google account will be ignored.

If i deploy my apps script, is there any method to know which user is browsing it just by checking the google account they use. I don't want to create custom user/pass to login. I just want the script can detect by active google account to personalize the page so they don't need to see all available the task but only can see specific task that they are assigned to.

Comment: Just to clarify : My post has been flagged as 'has been answer' but the fact that 's not the answer i'm looking fo. I've chosen the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66342797/16125139

This should help you

```js
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

Comment: it works for me and solve my problem. I don't know why someone put -1.